date picker scroller with vue js 2
I would like to create a date picker (with vue js 2) like this photo, so I can
use it in mobile view.
enter image description here
can anyone help me ?
I was trying to find any package but it has been very difficult to find one that have the layout . just normal calendar with selection of dates.

Here's a similar one made with jQuery, it's not specifically used for dates but you could modify it to work for date picking :
https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/iOS-Data-Picker-jQuery.html
Here's a demo
